# $A\vdash \neg B \to \neg(A\to B)$ by Mendelson's axioms

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This deduction system by using axiomas is being a real pain. My professor is using Mendelson's axioms which are

Axiom 1: $(B\to (C\to B))$

Axiom 2: $(B\to (C\to D))\to ((B\to C)\to(B\to D))$

Axiom 3: $(\neg C\to \neg B)\to ((\neg C\to B)\to C)$

And the rule of Modus ponens: $A, A\to B\vdash B $

I'm also allowed to use the theorem of deduction: If $A,B\vdash C$
then $A\vdash B\to C$

How can I proof that  $A\vdash \neg B \to \neg(A\to B)$?

My attempt is to use the theorem of deduction so I would start by taking $A$ and $\neg B$ as hypothesis. But then what?

Comment: See Mendelson (6th ed) : [Lemma 1.11.f, page 31](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31).

Comment: The "strategy" is to start with $A, (A \to B) \vdash B$ (immediate by MP) and use *DT* to get : $A \vdash (A \to B) \to B$. Then "contrapose" it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Huh?  Mendelson gets, or should have gotten to avoid equivocation in his use of the word proof, (A->((A->B)->B))).  Then by a substitution in ((A->B)->(($\lnot$B)->($\lnot$A))) he would obtain (((A->B)->B)->(($\lnot$B)->($\lnot$(A->B)))).  Then by another lemma, (A->(($\lnot$B)->($\lnot$(A->B)))).  Except he can't use a substitution in a theorem, his setup of his system disallows such a thing.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - Mendelson's proof system uses axiom schemata; thus, he needs no subst.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sure, but ((A->B)->((¬B)->(¬A))) is not an axiom schemata.  So, he would have to instantiate a theorem schemata *in* the system for that to work.  But, his definition of a proof doesn't allow for an instantiation of theorem schemata.  *If* he could use the rule of inference (his system only allows for detachment), {(A->B), (B->C)} $\vdash$ (A->C), then he would need to prove (A->((A->B)->B)) and (((A->B)->B)->((¬B)->(¬(A->B)))) from the axiom schemata to use his idea to infer to (A->((¬B)->(¬(A->B)))).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Mendelson's system actually has a meta-theorem (NOT proven or even mentioned by Mendelson... his book doesn't even prove a single theorem which isn't an axiom *in* his system for the propositional calculus) that every single axiom or theorem starts with a '(' and ends with ')'.  You might find proving that a bit more involved than it looks like at first glance, since you need to show that all consequences of the axioms work out that way.

I'll use ~ instead of $\lnot$.

Hint: Note that the consequent in the right part of the sequent could be C in axiom 3.  In other words, assume (~(~(A->B))).

With that in mind:

Proof sketch:

Assume (~B).

Assume (~(~(A->B))).

Assume (~(A->B)).  Show that (~(~(A->B))) can follow and infer ((~(A->B))->(~(~(A->B)))).

Show that ((~(A->B))->(~(A->B))).

Then use axiom 3 to infer (A->B) under the scope of (~(~(A->B))).  Now, since you have A as a premiss, infer B.

Thus, you can infer ((~(~(A->B)))->B).

Then assume (~(~(A->B))) again and show (~B).  Thus, you can infer ((~(~(A->B)))->(~B)).

Using axiom 3, you get (~(A->B)).

And discharging (~B) we have ((~B)->(~(A->B))).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow your proof. Can you please explain why can we assume $(\lnot ( \lnot (A \to B)))$? I'm also having problem with following Mendelson's proof. There he implicitly assumes $A \to B$ on start.

Comment: @shcolf Any well-formed formula can get assumed.  Take a look at axiom three. It says that if you can show a negation to lead to some well-formed formula B, and it's negation, then you can eventually infer the opposite of the negation.  So, to infer (¬(A→B)), (¬(¬(A→B))) gets assumed and B gets shown to follow allowing us to infer ( (¬(¬(A→B)))→B), and then (¬(¬(A→B))) gets assumed again and ($\lnot$B) gets shown to follow, allowing us to infer (¬(¬(A→B)))→($\lnot$B)).  Then axiom 3 gets used to infer to (¬(A→B))